# Is there a function that highlights items you can interact with upon keypress?

Tags: the-witcher-2

The first game had a function that would on keypress highlight the name of any items on screen that you could interact with or take. This was useful to quickly find everything you could take.

I haven't been able to find such a function yet in the Witcher 2. Is it just not there or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I now found the function, it is called "use medallion" and mapped to the `Z` key (or `Y` in german). When using the medallion you highlight all items in the vicinity for a short while, although the highlighting effect is pretty subtle.

The use of the medallion also shows you places of power and highlights enemies.