# Is there an easy way to identify what's lootable and what isn't?

Tags: the-witcher-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Key to highlight items in the Witcher 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22392/key-to-highlight-items-in-the-witcher-2)

One of my main frustrations in Witcher 2 so far is that whenever I run into a room filled with loot, I'm forced to spend minutes running Geralt like an idiot into every object that looks like it might contain loot until that special pop-up appears. Is there any pattern or special appearance to lootable objects, or is this something I'm simply going to have to live with?

Comment: [Just use the `z` key for your medallion](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22392/key-to-highlight-items-in-the-witcher-2)

Comment: it's the `y` key on the QWERTZ (german) layout.